# Query SQL table for Right To Left Markers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large localization system that contains translations for 26 languages, two of which are right to left (Arabic and Hebrew). Test found a few defective strings in the software deliverable that were traced back to the translators (not including the RTL marker in the appropriate location in the string). I happened to be in my IDE at the time and wrote a quick console app using EF to generate a list of all of the strings recently translated which were missing the maker (\u200f) to expedite the investigation as not all strings require them.

In an effort to add this to our QA process down the road, I wanted to create a stored procedure to perform the query. For the life of me I cannot get it to work and cannot find any documentation on querying against the character.

What I have found is that the RTL marker is NCHAR(8207) in Unicode codepoint or NCHAR(0x200F) in hex. My database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.

However, a query like:

```
declare @RTLM nchar
set @RTLM = NCHAR(8207)


  SELECT [Translation]
  FROM [dbo].[Translations]
  where Translation like '%' + @RTLM +'%'

GO
```

Returns every string in the table, regardless of whether or not it includes the RTL marker. The same query works fine if I am looking for a printable character in the query. The same behavior is present for the hex version NCHAR(0x200F).

Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be happening?

Comment: Does the marker appers anywhere on the parsisted string? Or maybe it should only appear at the beggining (or at the end)... Have you tryed using just one % to see what happens?

Comment: Another thing to test is the presence of that (invisible) char on everyone of your strings (something that your front-end could be doing - for instance)... Have you tried to replace this char with another visible one on your select, just to check if those returned rows son't contain this char for sure?

Comment: I can confirm that both a replace with a visible, printable character yields no string replacements and processing it in code (i.e. c# console app using EF as an ORM does not detect \u200f in any of the strings which do not have them (including strings in English and 23 other non-RTL languages). 

I should have been more clear, the query above returns *every* entry in the table, even non-RTL strings (212,000 strings).

Comment: what about re-writing it leaving the LIKE off and using a CHARINDEX instead? Wildly guessing cause it may be a limitation of the LIKE operator with those special chars.

Comment: Interesting results but still no success. Rewriting the where clause as WHERE CHARINDEX(@RTLM, [Translation]) > 0 causes only 76 strings to be returned from the table. True, all 76 strings have the RTL marker (confirmed in C# app), but the other 2500+ strings that have it are not returned in the query.

Comment: I'm closer to post it as an answer now... Just confirm that if you use it as WHERE CHARINDEX(@RTLM, [Translation]) >= 0 (I guess strings in this case may be 0 index based). And sorry for not being more assertive on my assumptions, but I really think that it will be faster for you to test than for me to replicate a testable environment.

Answer (score 0):

Wildly guessing that this may be a limitation of SQLServer's operator LIKE with those special characters.

As an alternative path I would suggest you to rewrite your query using the CHARINDEX function instead of the LIKE operator.

Comment: Same comment above Marcelo. Using CHARINDEX > 0 returns a total of 76 strings (there are over 2500 that have the RTL marker). >= returns all of the strings in the database. MSDN documentation for CHARINDEX states: This function returns 0 if the search character expression is not found in character expression. It is 1 based, not zero based.

Comment: I guess that the answer lies on finding what differentiate those 76 returned rows from the rest of the non-reurned that contains a RTL char on it... May be the position of the RTL on the string? Or the number of occurences of the special char?

Comment: Occurrences is only one instance in both detected and undetected results. Position varies both there is intersection in the result set (string with RTL marker at character 7 in one string is detected but not in another). At this point I am just going to take the performance hit and do it in code as it is 100% accurate and SSMS is leaving a lot to be desired in attempting to do this in SQL.

Comment: I should mention that I do doing all of my analysis with a hex editor. The RTL marker in hex is e2 80 8f. All results confirmed in Notepad++ hex edit plugin.

Comment: Well, as you apparently is talking about production environment, i would encourage you to solve by code (if that's a possible and confirmed solution). If I should come across anything that would help clarify a bit more this issue, i will post here just for the sake of future and other's reference...